# How to convert (cast) int to ntext

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to convert `int` field like `1005` to `ntext` alike `Alarm1005`, but `CAST(ID as ntext)` doesn't work, so how can I convert(cast) `int` to `ntext` ?

Comment: Don't use `NTEXT` - it's deprecated (as of SQL Server 2005) and should be avoided. Use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead

Comment: I just found this question because I have the same one. In my case I am using a SQL Server 2000 DB that has an NTEXT column. Not much I can do to change the circumstances other than try to cast or convert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CAST(CAST(ID as nvarchar(10)) as ntext)`?

**EDIT**

As *gbn* has justly hinted, `nvarchar(max)` is actually a much more preferable type for storing large string data.

Two reasons:

1. You have plenty of [functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx) that work with `nvarchar` as compared to those that can handle `ntext`.
2. The types `ntext`, `text` and `image` are [officially](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) deprecated.

And one other tiny reason is, you wouldn't have to double cast. It would be as simple as `CAST(ID AS nvarchar(10))` or `CAST(ID AS nvarchar(max))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD new_column NTEXT
UPDATE MyTable SET new_column = cast(old_column as nvarchar(16))
ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP COLUMN old_column
```